# RaiseError from predefined function is getting called when I use it to define another function

Tags: python

I am working on a project for university and I am having trouble with raising errors.
I am supposed to create several functions that will eventually be re-used in even more functions that I am about to create. I am supposed to use `Raise ValueError` when some specific arguments are being used. Yet, when I use the initial functions to define new functions, the ValueError that gets raised is the initial one and not the new one.

```
def first_function(arg1):
    if isinstance(arg1, tuple):
        return True
    else:
        raise ValueError("This is not a tuple")


def second_function(arg2):
    if first_function(arg2):
        print("That Is Indeed a Tuple")
    else:
        raise ValueError("This is really not a tuple")


argument = "(1, 1)"
print(second_function(argument))
# output: ValueError: This is not a tuple
# desired output: ValueError: This is really not a tuple
```

How can I fix this? I am not supposed to repeat code. I am supposed to keep re-using the functions I build, yet the errors seem to interfere.

Comment: I actually get `ValueError: ErrorText2` when running your code. That is the desired value, yes?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: What's the point of `first_function`? Either return `False` if `arg1` is *not* a tuple, or just skip calling `first_function` altogether and let whatever expected a tuple to raise an error.

Comment: Put another way, if a function can only return a single value, it may as well return `None`, because the return value doesn't carry any information beyond "this function returned without raising an exception".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, technically, the `"This is not a tuple"` error is functioning correctly. The error will stop the code - where the error happens - and report on the stack in that state. This is desirable.

That said, you can use a `try/except/finally` to catch the first error and pass it back to the second function, which is what I think you're trying to do.

```
def first_function(arg1):
    if isinstance(arg1, tuple):
        return True
    else:
        raise ValueError("This is not a tuple")


def second_function(arg2):
    # The try statement wraps the if/then/else
    try: 
        # When you call first_function, it will error
        # That error will be recognized and passed to 
        # second_function's "except" statement
        if first_function(arg2):
            print("That Is Indeed a Tuple")
        # This else is probably not necessary
        # Since first_function will either work (return True), or
        #  raise an error, you will never have a situation where 
        # "if first_function(arg2):" will ever reach this else 
        # else:
        #    raise ValueError("This is not a tuple")
    except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("This is really not a tuple")


argument = "(1, 1)"
print(second_function(argument))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rightmire/eclipse-workspace/junkcode/test.py", line 18, in second_function
    if first_function(arg2):
  File "/home/rightmire/eclipse-workspace/junkcode/test.py", line 6, in first_function
    raise ValueError("This is not a tuple")
ValueError: This is not a tuple

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rightmire/eclipse-workspace/junkcode/test.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(second_function(argument))
  File "/home/rightmire/eclipse-workspace/junkcode/test.py", line 23, in second_function
    raise ValueError("This is really not a tuple")
ValueError: This is really not a tuple
```

**As an aside...**

The functional goal you're usually trying to accomplish with this type of design pattern, is to avoid the need to do checks like you're doing in `first_function` (where it checks if the arg is a tuple).

This design pattern is usually so you can leave the error checking to the main calling method, and all the called methods can just do their thing - raising errors if bad code is sent.

I.e.

```
def first_function(arg1):
    return arg1.append("I should be a list")


def second_function(arg2):
    try: 
        _list = first_function(arg2)
        print("arg2 is, indeed, a list")
    except Exception as e:
        raise ValueError("You did not pass a list (ORIG ERROR: {}".format(e))

argument = "(1, 1)"
print(second_function(argument))
```

OUTPUT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rightmire/eclipse-workspace/junkcode/test.py", line 7, in second_function
    _list = first_function(arg2)
  File "/home/rightmire/eclipse-workspace/junkcode/test.py", line 2, in first_function
    arg1.append("I should be a list")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rightmire/eclipse-workspace/junkcode/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(second_function(argument))
  File "/home/rightmire/eclipse-workspace/junkcode/test.py", line 10, in second_function
    raise ValueError("You did not pass a list (ORIG ERROR: {}".format(e))
ValueError: You did not pass a list (ORIG ERROR: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Functionally, the `try/except/finally` is used to silence errors. As an example...

```
def first_function(_list, arg1):
    _list.append(int(arg1))
    return _list

def second_function():
    _list = []
    while True:
        arg2 = input("Enter an integer:")
        try: 
            _list = first_function(_list, arg2)
            print("a list containing {}".format(_list))
        except Exception as e:
            print ("You did not pass an integer. Try again")

second_function()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Enter an integer:1
a list containing [1]

Enter an integer:2
a list containing [1, 2]

Enter an integer:3
a list containing [1, 2, 3]

Enter an integer:r
You did not pass an integer. Try again

Enter an integer:4
a list containing [1, 2, 3, 4]
Enter an integer:
```

Comment: Sorry, let me edit and write a better-difined code.